# How to remove a specific holiday from Pandas USFederalHolidayCalendar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, object

I'm trying to remove Columbus Day from `pandas.tseries.holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar`.

This seems to be possible, as a one-time operation, with

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
cal = cal.rules.pop(6)
```

However, if this code is within a function that gets called repeatedly (in a loop) to generate several independent outputs, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

It gives me the impression that the object remains in its initial loaded state and as the loop progresses it pops holidays at index 6 until they're gone and then throws an error.

I tried reloading via `importlib.reload` to no avail.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. You've overwritten the entire calendar (`cal`) with the result of poping the rules. `pop` only returns the removed element, so you've reduced `cal` from a calendar (`<class 'pandas.tseries.holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar'>`) to a single rule (`<class 'pandas.tseries.holiday.Holiday'>`).

Comment: when doing this in debug panel, I see only the popped element disappear, while `cal` remains otherwise intact, i.e., the remaining rules are still there after `pop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Import your library
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

# Get an id of 'columbus' in 'rules' list
columbus_index = USFederalHolidayCalendar().rules.index([i for i in USFederalHolidayCalendar().rules if 'Columbus' in str(i)][0])

# Create your own class, inherit 'USFederalHolidayCalendar'
class USFederalHolidayCalendar(USFederalHolidayCalendar):
    # Exclude 'columbus' entry
    rules = USFederalHolidayCalendar().rules[:columbus_index] + USFederalHolidayCalendar().rules[columbus_index+1:]

# Create an object from your class
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
print(cal.rules)
```

```
[Holiday: New Years Day (month=1, day=1, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f6afad571f0>),
 Holiday: Martin Luther King Jr. Day (month=1, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+3)>),
 Holiday: Presidents Day (month=2, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+3)>),
 Holiday: Memorial Day (month=5, day=31, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(-1)>),
 Holiday: July 4th (month=7, day=4, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f6afad571f0>),
 Holiday: Labor Day (month=9, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+1)>),
 Holiday: Veterans Day (month=11, day=11, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f6afad571f0>),
 Holiday: Thanksgiving (month=11, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=TH(+4)>),
 Holiday: Christmas (month=12, day=25, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x7f6afad571f0>)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `rules` is a **class attribute** (a list of objects). See the code taken from [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c021d33ecf0e096a186edb731964767e9288a875/pandas/tseries/holiday.py#L551):

```
class USFederalHolidayCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    """
    US Federal Government Holiday Calendar based on rules specified by:
    https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/
       snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/
    """

    rules = [
        Holiday("New Years Day", month=1, day=1, observance=nearest_workday),
        USMartinLutherKingJr,
        USPresidentsDay,
        USMemorialDay,
        Holiday("July 4th", month=7, day=4, observance=nearest_workday),
        USLaborDay,
        USColumbusDay,
        Holiday("Veterans Day", month=11, day=11, observance=nearest_workday),
        USThanksgivingDay,
        Holiday("Christmas", month=12, day=25, observance=nearest_workday),
    ]
```

Since the attribute is defined on the class, there is only one underlying list referred to, so if operations on different instances of that class both attempt to edit the list, then you'll have some unwanted behavior. Here is an example that shows what's going on:

```
>>> class A:
...     rules = [0,1,2]
... 
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = A()
>>> a1.rules.pop()
2
>>> a1.rules.pop()
1
>>> a2.rules.pop()
0
>>> a2.rules.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
>>> a3 = A()
>>> a3.rules
[]
```

Also, each module in python is imported only one time

Comment: thanks... do you see any solution for removing a specific holiday?

Comment: @pepe Maybe a deep copy of the rules list before removing any element??